# How to compare big integers stored in int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, biginteger, compareto

I am trying to implement BigInteger class in C#. Right now I am stuck at a method called `isLessThan(HugeInteger b)`. This is my class and the corresponding methods.

```
class HugeInteger
{
    public int[] array = new int[40];

    public HugeInteger(String s)
    {
        this.input(s);
    } // end constructor

    /*To read a huge integer having upto 40 digits, I am using an integer array to store 
      these values(input is read as a string for this matter) and later on will override 
      ToString() for output if needed.*/
    private void input(String s)
    {
        char[] charInteger = s.ToCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 39 - charInteger.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 39 - charInteger.Length + 1; i <= 39; i++)
        {

            array[i] = int.Parse(charInteger[index].ToString());
            index++;
        }
    }

    public bool isLessThan(HugeInteger that)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 39; i++)
        {
            if (this.array[i] < that.array[i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically, I have 40 digits stored into an integer array for every HugeInteger object. But I know for sure that my method `isLessThan(HugeInteger b)` is wrong and that there is something simple I am overlooking. So how should I go about making a right `isLessthan(HugeInteger b)` method?

Edit:
My isLessThan method doesn't work for some cases like if I try to compare "9873" and "75", I get `true`, but I need a `false`. Sorry for not being clear.

Note: I give my inputs(like 9873 or 75) as a string and then parse them to int in my `input` method and then store them into integer array.

Comment: so tell us at least what is wrong or what you are expecting..?

Comment: side note: do not use *magic numbers*, i.e. `40`, `39` but declare a constant

Comment: I assume this is for homework, otherwise there is already a `BigInteger` class in C#.

Comment: When you create an `int` array it defaults to all zeros and you don't need to loop through and set each index to zero.

Comment: @MethodMan Yes I have edited my question. Thanks

Comment: @juharr This is not my homework, but I am practicing it anyway since it's in my textbook. and thanks for telling, I guess I don't need that extra loop(will remove that later on).

Comment: It's fine to **use** 40, but @DmitryBychenko is saying you should have a constant somewhere that's set to 40 and use the constant everywhere instead. That way, if you wake up tomorrow and decide to change it to 50, you only have to change the value of the constant.

Comment: @Blasttrash I think that you do not understand the comment about not using magic numbers..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh ok. Thanks. I guess that would make things easier if the code gets too big.

Comment: Also it's better to do something like `i < 40` or really at that point you can just do `i < array.Length`.

Comment: @AdamV Yeah I figured that out just now, so I deleted my previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's implement the comparisons; the typical way uses universal comparison (in some languages it's even has a special operator `<=>`)

```
  class HugeInteger {
    ...

    // Universal comparator
    //  +1 left > right
    //   0 left == right
    //  -1 left < right
    public static int Compare(HugeInteger left, HugeInteger right) {
      // first, we should deal with null's; let null be the leaset possible value

      // left and right are just the references of one inctance?
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right)) 
        return 0;
      else if (left == null)
        return -1;
      else if (right == null)
        return 1;

      // Now we checked for null, let's compare both arrays  

      //DONE: no 39, 40 or other magic numbers, but Length 
      for (int i = 0; i < left.array.Length; ++i)
        if (left.array[i] < right.array[i])
          return -1;
        else if (left.array[i] > right.array[i])
          return 1;

      return 0; // no differences found, so left equals to right
    }
```

Having comparator implemented it's very easy to write `isLessThan`, `isGreaterThan`:

```
    public bool isLessThan(HugeInteger other) {
      return Compare(this, other) < 0;
    }

    public bool isGreaterThan(HugeInteger other) {
      return Compare(this, other) > 0;
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fix your method

```
public bool isLessThan(HugeInteger that)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 39; i++)
    {
        if (this.array[i] < that.array[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.array[i] > that.array[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically when you compare the digits if they are not equal then you know if one is greater than or less than the other.  You only continue if they are equal.  What you currently have is just checking if there is at least one corresponding digit in the first number that is less than the second.  So for 9873 and 75 it's true because 3 < 5.  Where as with my change it will return false as soon as it compares 9 and 0.

Comment: Sorry, but what if I call `myHugeInteger.isLessThan(null)`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I was attempting to explain and cover the general cases as this is only a learning exercise of the OP, but of course `null` checks would be something that they would want to add, but maybe a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

When an overflow is incurred, the CPU's condition codes are set such that a subsequent instruction may FAIL to deliver the proper result, so all your fancy logic is for naught if you don't predict overflows BEFORE they occur.

(You can't DETECT an overflow: if I ask, for example,

if( MUCHTOOLARGENUMBER > SOMEREASONABLEVALUE ) {

then I have NO GUARANTEE which way the test will evaluate.)

Comment: If I remember right, in most of the languages(at least C based), if I increment a number beyond it's maximum value, it gets wrapped back to the minimum value right? (and vice versa with decrementing beyond a min as well).

Comment: That is true--details are architecture-dependent, of course--but my point is that, after an overflow mucks with the processor's condition codes, the result of a SUBSEQUENT test or test-and-branch may not be reliable.